# seguimiento de ruta en mapbox

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

estoy desarrollando una pagina que usa mapbox y los datos de posicionamiento por telemetría del html5 mi duda es la siguiente, mi código ya posiciona el icono en mi posición aproximada, el problema es que no se como actualizar la posición cada n segundos y que trace una linea por don de he pasado.
Este es mi código:



    
    
    GPS
    
    https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.49.0/mapbox-gl.js'>
    https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.49.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    
    
    
            body { margin:0; padding:0; }
            #map { position:absolute; top:100; bottom:100; width:50%; padding-left: 10cm;}
    
         
         
             html, body {
                 font: 16pt arial;
             }

```
         #viz {
             width: 900px;
             height: 700px;
             border: 1px solid lightgray;
             font: 22pt arial;
         }
     </style>
     <script type="text/javascript">

         var viz;
                                    /*database connector*/
         function draw() {
             var config = {
                 container_id: "viz",
                 server_url: "bolt://localhost:7687",
                 server_user: "neo4j",
                 server_password: "Modular1",

                 initial_cypher: "MATCH (n:Auto) RETURN (n) limit 10"
             };

             viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
             viz.render();
         }
     </script>
```

Mostrar ubicación 
    Origen: 
    
    
            .marker {
                display: block;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 50%;
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 0;
            }

```
</div>
<script>
    var latitude;
    var longitude;

    var coordinate = longDouble.toString() + "+" + latDouble.toString(); /*append coordinates*/

function myCoordenada() 
{
 document.getElementById("origen").value = coordinate;
}
function EncuentraMe()
{
    var output = document.getElementById('map');
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {

    }
    else
    {


    }
    function localizacion(posicion)
{   

         latitude = posicion.coords.latitude;
         longitude = posicion.coords.longitude;

   mapa();

}
function mapa(){
mapboxgl.accessToken = '';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // contenedor id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // estilo del mapa
    center: [longitude, latitude], // punto de origen [lng, lat]
    zoom: 15 // zoom inicial
});
map.on('load', function() {
map.loadImage('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/car-vol-7/512/2-512.png', function(error, image) {
    if (error) throw error;
    map.addImage('car', image); //my custom image
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "points",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "car",
            "icon-size": 0.040 
        }
    });
});
```

});
    }
    function error()
    {
        output.innerHTML = "

Su ubicación no esta disponible

";
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(localizacion,error);

```
}
</script>
<div id='map'></div>



</body>
```

**según la documentación oficial**
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/
debo poner la coordenada original y la final para dibujar la ruta, mi duda es debo poner un do while en la función "encuentrame()" para que este refrescando la posición?; De antemano agradezco cualquier sugerencia ya que estoy totalmente perdido